# Aggregation and Condition in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I am new to MongoDB. I have the following collection : `CallLeg` which contains the data in the following format

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bf5504a937eb609c4d020e4"),
    "startedAt" : ISODate("2018-11-21T17:50:45.909Z"),
    "endedAt" : ISODate("2018-11-21T18:02:09.909Z"),
    "cc" : "91",
    "phone" : "1234567890",
    "type" : "pstn",
    "status" : true,
    "channel" : "mF4YnGi7SM4qCeKHJ6SYunqkano2BNQQ",
    "cost" : 0,
    "duration" : 0,
    "cid" : "ABCDEFGH"

}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bf5504a937eb609c4d020e5"),
    "startedAt" : ISODate("2018-11-21T17:50:10.110Z"),
    "endedAt" : ISODate("2018-11-21T18:02:10.110Z"),
    "cc" : "91",
    "phone" : "0007654321",
    "type" : "voip",
    "status" : true,
    "channel" : "mF4YnGi7SM4qCeKHJ6SYunqkano2BNQQ",
    "cost" : 0,
    "duration" : 0,
    "cid" : "ABCDEFGH"

}
```

I want to get the output as follows :

- If cid is same for 'n' objects, it should return those objects. Let's say it returns 2
- Then if `obj1` has `type=pstn` and `obj2` has `type=voip` it should return answer as `MIXED`, if `obj1_type = obj2_type = voip` it should return `VOIP`  and similar for `pstn` for the same `cid`.

Hope I am clear with my question.

Comment: This is what I have tried so far : 
`db.CallLeg.aggregate([ {$match: {cid: "ABCDEFGH"}, }] ` . But unable to build query ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.CallLeg.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$cid",
            objects: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { objects: { $size: 2 } }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            answer: {
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        { case: { $allElementsTrue: [ 
                            { $map: { input: "$objects", as: "o", in: { $eq: [ "$$o.type", "voip" ] } } } ] } , then: "voip" },
                        { case: { $allElementsTrue: [ 
                            { $map: { input: "$objects", as: "o", in: { $eq: [ "$$o.type", "pstn" ] } } } ] } , then: "pstn" },
                    ],
                    default: "MIXED"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Basically you need to [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by `cid` to compare multiple documents with each other. You can also add `$match` before `$group` if you need to analyze only one `cid`. Then you can use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to check the number of "same" objects. In the last stage you need to compare the elements in `objects` array. You can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to get an array of boolean values which will indicate how many `voip` and `pstns` values you have. Then you need [$allElementsTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/) to check if you have one type for all items. Everything can be placed inside [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/index.html) to define last, default branch which is `MIXED`

Comment: mickl,  while trying your query I get the following response : 

`"errmsg" : "bad query: BadValue: unknown top level operator: $expr",`

Comment: @AniketMaithani you must be using MongoDB in version lower that 3.6, but that's not a problem, modified my answer, you can verify it here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/cI1aH1Wd9CX

Comment: mickl, thanks for your answer. Yes, I am using mongo 3.2.21 . Now I get the following error : `Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields`

Comment: Any chance to upgrade to 3.4 ?

Comment: I have upgraded it to 3.4 ? Should I try your answer now ?

Comment: Sure, 3.4 should be enough :)

Comment: I have updated the mongodb to 3.4 . Seems like everything is fine but I am unable to see the output of the query. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Try to compare your data with mongoplayground I've pasted and remember that there's a $match condition which requires exactly two elements so you can try without that condition